# iFrameResizer - readyCallback seems never called

Tags: iframe, iframe-resizer

I am trying to use method `readyCallback()` in [iFrameResizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer), but it does not seem to work. When I add the callback to `parent iframe` object, it is never called:

```
iFrameResize({
    log : true,
    checkOrigin: false,
    minHeight : 800,
    maxHeight : 4000,
    readyCallback: function(){
        // (!) never called
        console.log('ready parent callback .. '); 
    },
    messageCallback: function(data){
        // works OK
        console.log('message callback .. '); 
        console.log(data);
    },
    initCallback: function(){
        // works OK
        window.scrollTo(0,0); 
        alert("OK initiated");
    }, 
    resizedCallback : function(info){ 
        // works OK
        console.log(info);
        scrollTo(0, info.iframe.offsetTop);
    },
    heightCalculationMethod : 'taggedElement'
}, '#iframe123');
```

The `iframeResizer.contentWindow.js` inside iframe element loads and works OK.

Am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that method `readyCallback` was in wrong place. Here is working setup:

**Parent page** with iframe element:

```
iFrameResize({
    log : true,
    checkOrigin: false,
    minHeight : 800,
    maxHeight : 4000,
    messageCallback: function(data){
        console.log('message callback .. '); 
        console.log(data);
        // scroll to top edge of iframe element
        scrollTo(0, data.iframe.offsetTop);
    },
    initCallback: function(){
        console.log("OK initiated");
        window.scrollTo(0,0); 
    }, 
    resizedCallback : function(info){ 
        console.log(info);
        scrollTo(0, info.iframe.offsetTop);
    },
    heightCalculationMethod : 'taggedElement'
}, '#iframe123');
```

**Inside iframe** element with loaded `iframeResizer.contentWindow.js`:

```
// solution 1:
window.iFrameResizer = {
    readyCallback: function(){
        // scroll parent to top edge of iframe element
        window.parentIFrame.scrollToOffset(0,0);
    }
}

// solution 2:
window.iFrameResizer = {
    readyCallback: function(){
      if('parentIFrame' in window){
          parentIFrame.sendMessage('Loaded iframe ['+window.parentIFrame.getId()+'].');
      }
    }
}

// load content window at the end
<script src="/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.js"></script>
```